# How to disable download window in firefox with watir-webdriver?

Tags: firefox, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I don't want to handle download window in Firefox or IE. I want to auto download the excel file without any download window. I have tried to set several configuration parameters for Firefox, but it didn't work.
In my test I'm trying to download excel file

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.lastDir'] = 'C:\\Downloads'
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = 'C:\\Downloads'
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting'] = false
profile['browser.download.manager.addToRecentDocs'] = true

profile['browser.download.manager.useWindow'] = false
profile['browser.download.useDownloadDir'] = true
profile['browser.download.show_plugins_in_list'] = true
profile['browser.download.manager.openDelay'] = 100000
profile['browser.download.animateNotifications'] = false

driver = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Still the browser displaying download window when my script performs click operation on download button

Currently I'm using Firefox 35.0.1 on Windows-7(64bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries), you should use the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference to achieve this. Value is defined as

> A comma-separated list of MIME types to save to disk without asking
>   what to use to open the file. Default value is an empty string.

I am not very good at `Ruby`, but it will probably look something like

```
profile["browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"] = "text/plain, application/octet-stream"
```

Just use the correct MIME type.

---

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839544/using-selenium-webdrivers-method-browser-helperapps-neverask-savetodisk-how-ca), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146403/disable-firefox-save-as-dialog-selenium) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473354/firefox-4-with-watir-webdriver-need-help-using-helperapps-neverask-to-save-csv?rq=1) answer.