# How to disable download dialogue in Internet Explorer with Watir-webdriver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I want set some capabilities like enabling auto download option(Disable Download dialogue). I also want to disable all the dialogues like 'Would you like to store your password?', 'Would you like to make Internet Explorer your default browser?'

How we can set it with Watir-webdriver API? I want all these settings within the automation script, like the desiredCapabilities of IE browser

Comment: I do not think you can do it in IE

Comment: oh..!! Do you have any idea how to watch all the configuration parameters of IE? like 'about:config' in Firefox

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable download window in firefox and IE, with watir-webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262889/how-to-disable-download-window-in-firefox-and-ie-with-watir-webdriver)

Comment: The other question is also posted by me. I haven't get any solution related to Internet explorer there. hence I have posted a separate question specific for IE. Also I made some changes to previous  question to make it specific for Firefox. Thanks

Comment: is there any known issue related to IE configuration setup?